# jquery mobile href sms android

Tags: jquery, mobile, sms, send

I want to send an SMS with this code:

```
 <a href="sms:؟body=sdsadweqw">Invite a friend by SMS</a>
```

but it doesn't work -- I get an SMS without body (it's empty).

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 4):

`<a href="sms:+1234567890?body=message">SMS Link</a>`
You have no number and it looks like you're using `؟` instead of a question mark `?`.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your email client, some email clients only take the phone number and ignore anything after.

on iOS if you want to add body, try adding ";" instead of "?"

```
sms://000-000-0000;body=hello+world
```